# Convert hex string representation to hex number in SQL Server T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cast, hex

I have been given a dataset where hexadecimal numbers have been stored as a quasi-hex string representation intended to be human-friendly, e.g. "16A1". Is there a conversion function in T-SQL that will convert the string '16A1', or a modified version of it, into the hex number `0x000016A1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a function to specifically do that but it's easy enough to accomplish with the following:

```
SELECT 
  '0x' + RIGHT('00000000' + '16A1', 8) AS SomeHexString
```

[Example dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/XXwlwugh)

---

As in line with the other suggestions you could also cast the value to hex with the `BINARY` data type like so:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT
    (
        BINARY(4),
        RIGHT
        (
            CONCAT('00000000', '16A1'),
            8
        ),
        2
    ) AS SomeHexField
```

This should account for varying length values in your quasi-hex string.

[Example dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/N58DlwXq)

---

If the input hex string can be nullable, make sure to un-null it with `ISNULL()`, `COALESCE()` or switching the `+` operator inside the `RIGHT()` function to a `CONCAT()` function (like my second option) instead.

Comment: Why not actually make it a hex value? `SELECT b4 = CONVERT(binary(4), CONCAT('0000', '16A1'), 2);`

Comment: Thank you both.  The answer and the comment gave me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can just convert it to `binary(2)` with style 2, and then concat it with `0x0000` (the binary value, not a string)

```sql
SELECT 0x0000 + CONVERT(binary(2), '16A1', 2);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9kabmz5d)

Comment: Does this work if the input value changes length?

Comment: No, but it doesn't hugely make sense anyway then, because hex values are little-endian ie the first byte should be on the right not the left.

Comment: Meant to say left not right